# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not navigate to webview; there are none

Tags: ios, webview, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, simulator

### Desired capabilities

"appium:platformName": "iOS",
"appium:platformVersion": "15.0",
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 13 pro Max",
"appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
"udid": "0B2392E0-F3A7-4860-8E01-98C2B43EE6C9",
"autoWebview": "true"

**ENVIRONMENT:**
1)Appium Server GUI : 1.22.0
2)Xcode - 13.0
3)appium inspector - 2022.2.1
4)Java - 18.0.2.1
5)Selenium - 3.11.0
6)java-client - 6.0.0-BETA5
7)Eclipse-Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
8)os.name: 'Mac OS X
9)os.version: '12.5.1'

**NOTE:**
It works fine on browserstack but the issue is observed when i  try to switch to webview on local. Is there any other capabilities that I need to add to switch the context from native to webview

**Appium logs**

```
[RemoteDebugger] Checking for bundle identifiers: com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-SafariViewService, com.apple.SafariViewService, *, xxxxx
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'process-SafariViewService'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'com.apple.SafariViewService'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle '*'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'xxxxxxx'
[RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:41591 (try #1 of 20)
[RemoteDebugger] Attempting app 'PID:41591'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to app 'PID:41591' (id: 376): 'connectToApp'
[RemoteDebugger] Received response from send (id: 376): '["PID:41591",{}]'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 1ms
[RemoteDebugger] Empty page dictionary received
[RemoteDebugger] Error checking application: 'Empty page dictionary received'. Retrying connection
[RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[RemoteDebugger]     Application: "PID:41591"
[RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:41591"
[RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[RemoteDebugger]         isActive: true
[RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown"
[RemoteDebugger]     Application: "PID:41592"
[RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:41592"
[RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.Networking"
[RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.Networking"
[RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[RemoteDebugger]         isActive: true
[RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown"
[RemoteDebugger]     Application: "PID:41589"
[RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:41589"
[RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[RemoteDebugger]         name: "xxxxxx"
[RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-Zetadocs.Approval.Mobile.iOS"
[RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[RemoteDebugger]         isActive: true
[RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: "Unknown"
[RemoteDebugger] Checking for bundle identifiers: com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent, process-SafariViewService, com.apple.SafariViewService, *, xxxxxxx
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'process-SafariViewService'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'com.apple.SafariViewService'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle '*'
[RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:41591' for bundle 'xxxxxx'
[RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:41591 (try #1 of 20)
[RemoteDebugger] Attempting app 'PID:41591'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to app 'PID:41591' (id: 378): 'connectToApp'
[RemoteDebugger] Received response from send (id: 378): '["PID:41591",{}]'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 1ms
[RemoteDebugger] Empty page dictionary received
[RemoteDebugger] Error checking application: 'Empty page dictionary received'. Retrying connection
[RemoteDebugger] Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
[XCUITest] No available web pages: Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
[XCUITest] No web frames found.
[XCUITest] {}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session/35db46e3-9aab-48f8-afe5-d6e11abe8ff1' to command name 'deleteSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /session/35db46e3-9aab-48f8-afe5-d6e11abe8ff1] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/2DAE2402-0733-43DC-A98E-1CDD488A2CA4] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":null,"sessionId":null}
[DevCon Factory] Releasing connections for 0B2392E0-F3A7-4860-8E01-98C2B43EE6C9 device on any port number
[DevCon Factory] Found cached connections to release: ["0B2392E0-F3A7-4860-8E01-98C2B43EE6C9:8100"]
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[XCUITest] Found a remote debugger session. Removing...
[RemoteDebugger] Disconnecting from remote debugger
[RemoteDebugger] Cleaning up listeners
[IOSSimulatorLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1664949451836 (11:27:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not navigate to webview; there are none!
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:161:13)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at spinHandles (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:168:14)
[W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.navToViewWithTitle (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:186:3)
[W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.navToInitialWebview (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/context.js:222:5)
[W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.start (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:528:7)
[W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.createSession (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:262:7)
[W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:387:35)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 95464 ms - 677
[HTTP] 

Can anyone please help on this issue?
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Problem:
Whenever I launch my test suite on iphone 13 Pro Max simulator using XCUITest driver and appium 1.22.0 test fail randomly with the error "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not navigate to webview; there are none".
 What i noticed running the tests is the app launches and fails with the above mentioned error.

Comment: Please have a look on the attached appium logs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it by activating Safari Web-Inspector.

**Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector**

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by activating Safari Web-Inspector.

**Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector**

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I have already tried by activating the safari web inspector but still getting the same error. Could you please suggest any other solutions?